# template template argument deduction with sfinae

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae, template-templates

The template template argument can't be deduced for both `foo` and `foo2`.

If I remove the sfinae part, the template template argument was successfully deduced for both `foo` and `foo2`.

How to fix either the `span` class or `foo` and `foo2`?

Thanks.

Test (also at [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'%23include+%3Ctype_traits%3E%0A%0Atemplate%3Ctypename+T%3E%0Ausing+enable_if_t_const+%3D+typename+std::enable_if%3C%0A++++++++std::is_const%3CT%3E::value%0A%3E::type%3B%0A%0Atemplate%3Ctypename+T,+typename%3Dvoid%3E+class+span%3B%0A%0Atemplate%3Ctypename+T%3E%0Aclass+span%3CT,+enable_if_t_const%3CT%3E%3E+%7B%0Apublic:%0A++++explicit+span(const+T*+const+data)+%7B%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+T,+template%3Ctypename%3E+class+S%3E+%0Avoid+foo()+%7B%7D%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+T,+template%3Ctypename%3E+class+S%3E+%0Avoid+foo2(S%3CT%3E%26+s)+%7B%7D%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++int+arr%5B%5D+%3D+%7B1%7D%3B%0A++++span%3Cconst+int%3E+s(arr)%3B%0A++++foo%3Cconst+int,+span%3E()%3B%0A++++foo2(s)%3B%0A++++return+0%3B%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g73,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',trim:'0'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-Ofast',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+7.3+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4))

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
using enable_if_t_const = typename std::enable_if<
        std::is_const<T>::value
>::type;

template<typename T, typename=void> class span;

template<typename T>
class span<T, enable_if_t_const<T>> {
public:
    explicit span(const T* const data) {}
};

template <typename T, template<typename> class S> 
void foo() {}

template <typename T, template<typename> class S> 
void foo2(S<T>& s) {}

int main() {
    int arr[] = {1};
    span<const int> s(arr);
    foo<const int, span>();
    foo2(s);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Justin It compiles if you add `-std=c++17`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Apparently C++17 added something I wasn't aware of. I'll need to look into that

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I assume you mean it works in c++17.  Would you mind explaining in an answer, I'm curious.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe I don't know exact details, so I'll wait for someone else to write it.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Doesn't work with `-std=c++17` and clang though: https://godbolt.org/g/Yy1ZVj

Comment: Interesting. [This describes the behavior mentioned](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Template_template_arguments) by @HolyBlackCat , but it appears that clang hasn't implemented it

Comment: Justin surely appreciates the Check mark for his useful answer, but please wait a bit more to see if the c++17 resolution can materialize as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because, although you have a default template parameter, `span` isn't a `template <typename> class S`. It's a `template <typename, typename> class S`.

The easiest fix is to change it to

```
template <typename T, template<typename...> class S> 
void foo2(S<T>& s) {}
```

So that you can accept any `S` that takes any number of types (although we only use it with one).

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/g/73hxFU)

Comment: Changing `<typename...>` to `<typename, typename>` will make `foo` work but `foo2` will not work. Don't know why.

Comment: @Rzu If you change `foo2` to `<typename, typename>`, you also have to make it `foo2(S<T, void>& s) {}`

Comment: So I use the general class instead of any specialization of the class? Thanks.

Comment: Why does that parameter pack(`typename...`) work in this case? Hmm.

Comment: @Rzu When the compiler looks at the template function alone, it makes sense. There's a `template <typename...> class S`, and we "call" it with one type `S<T>`. When you pass in the `span` type, the template is instantiated, which is roughly like replacing `S` with `span`, so `S<T>` is `span<T>` which is `span<T, void>` because of the default parameter

Comment: Compilation is kind of slow. Don't know if that is because of the `typename...` or other templates.

Comment: @Rzu Slow compilation can be caused by a wide variety of things. It can be suboptimal project structure (stuff like one very large cpp file or a large amount of dependencies on headers), it can be heavy use of templates (note the [Rule of Chiel](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/6gur2x/the_rule_of_chiel_aka_compiletime_cost_of/?ref=share&ref_source=link); some things are more expensive than others). If you overuse SFINAE, that's something that can easily make it slow to compile

Comment: A comment in that rule of chiel reddit mentions `constexpr if` is faster than sfinae. I guess an auto return type and a `constexpr if`is faster than sfinae? I mean the example at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If Might have to try that if the compilation time gets too crazy.